# This standard ML function gives me `unhandled exception: Match`. Can someone point me in the right direction to solve the problem?

Tags: sml

I am trying to write a Standard ML function called 'select' that receives a list of integers and a function. The passed function receives an integer and returns a boolean (ex, fun isOdd 3 -> true).  The function is to go through each integer in the list and append them to a new list if the given function returns true for that integer.  So `select [1,2,3,4,5] isOdd` will return `[1,3,5]`.
This is the code I've got:

```
fun select (l : int list, f:int -> bool) = 
    let val newlist : int list = []
        fun recurse (x::xs) =
            if f(x)
                then newlist :: [x] :: recurse(xs)
            else
                newlist :: recurse(xs)
    in
        recurse(l : int list)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recurse` doesn't have a case for the empty list, so it will fail when you reach the empty list.

Let's fix that:

```
fun select (l : int list, f:int -> bool) = 
    let val newlist : int list = []
        fun recurse [] = []
          | recurse (x::xs) =
            if f(x)
                then newlist :: [x] :: recurse(xs)
            else
                newlist :: recurse(xs)
    in
        recurse l
    end
```

and test:

```
- select ([1,2,3,4], fn x => x mod 2 <> 0);
val it = [[],[1],[],[],[3],[]] : int list list
- select ([1], fn x => true);
val it = [[],[1]] : int list list
- select ([1], fn x => false);
val it = [[]] : int list list
```

That's no good – we want `[1,3]`, `[1]`, and `[]`.

The type of your function is

```
val select = fn : int list * (int -> bool) -> int list list
```

The `int list list` result is wrong; it should be `int list`.
This happens because the first element of the result from `recurse` is an `int list` – the empty `newlist` – so the result must be an `int list list`.

Fixing the problem gives

```
fun select (l : int list, f:int -> bool) = 
    let fun recurse [] = []
          | recurse (x::xs) =
            if f x
            then x :: recurse xs
            else recurse xs 
    in
        recurse l
    end
```

Note that the type constraints are fairly pointless; if you remove them you will get a much more useful polymorphic function.

Comment: Thank you much!  That definitely solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing molbdnilo's rewriting of `select`, besides removing the type constraints, having an inner function for recursion is not necessary either, as `select` itself can easily be recursive:

```
fun select ([], f) = []
  | select (x::xs, f) =
    if f x
    then x :: select (xs, f)
    else select (xs, f)
```